# web3auth gives me error

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am getting error: https://broadcast-server.tor.us/store/get?key=0441dcd1......  404 (Not Found) and 'Session likely expired' but I ca´t connect again because it does not shows to connect again

I was connected to testenet and it worked with safe-core-sdk>packages>auth-kit>example, but suddenly it gives me the error and the contaner does nos shows to connect again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling this method to clean the session?

```
await web3AuthModalPack.signOut()
```